# extract one field from json to form an array

Tags: javascript, json

I have an json array like this, I want to extract only the productId's to an array.

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "productId": "a01",
      "uuid": "124748ba-6fc4f"
    },
    {
      "productId": "b2",
      "uuid": "1249b9ba-64d"
    },
    {
      "productId": "c03",
      "uuid": "124c78da-64"
    },
    {
      "productId": "d04",
      "uuid": "124ee9da-6"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do this in Javascript. I am not that good in JS, kidnly help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.(`arr.map(callback[, thisArg])`)

```js
var input = {
  "products": [{
    "productId": "a01",
    "uuid": "124748ba-6fc4f"
  }, {
    "productId": "b2",
    "uuid": "1249b9ba-64d"
  }, {
    "productId": "c03",
    "uuid": "124c78da-64"
  }, {
    "productId": "d04",
    "uuid": "124ee9da-6"
  }]
};
var op = input.products.map(function(item) {
  return item.productId;
});
//Using arrow function-
//var op = input.products.map(item => item.productId);
console.log(op);
```